# How does the internationalization of Forensic Files work?

Tags: distribution, translation, forensic-files

The true crime docutainment series [*Forensic Files*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0247882/) is broadcast on German TV under its original title *Medical Detectives*. The episodes (and thus the actual cases) are thereby the original American ones, complete with the original interviewees, in documentary-style overdubbing. But usually they also feature **interview excepts with German forensic experts** and scientists. While they don't contribute directly to the actual case of the episode, they explain general forensic procedures and details related to the episode's storyline.

Now of course those German interviews are surely not part of the original episode, so I wonder **how the licensing and internationalization works** here. Usually with TV-series (and movies) they either air the original episode (though, with dialogue translation) or there are fully produced licensed copies of the show's *concept*, complete with local actors/settings (more common with non-fiction game shows and stuff, though). But here the **local distributor just added their own bits to the original episode**.

**How is this regulated in the case of *Forensic Files*?** Do the original episodes contain other interviews explaining the general forensic concepts in those places and have they been explicitly marked as the ones to be substituted by local distributors? Or do they not even contain those bits and they were just added in the German localization to enhance understandability/identification? Or is the German *Medical Detectives* actually to be seen as its very own distinct TV-show, while still taking the majority of the episodes from the original (though, this would still have to be licensed somehow)?

Comment: Related, but not a dupe: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88613/pbs-vs-bbc-civilizations